# Data fetching layer in React with Firebase Auth

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, graphql

I'm building a layer in my React app that will be responsible for executing GraphQL queries and mutations. I imagine having a function, say, `executeQuery(query, variables)`, that takes in the query to execute and variables, should there be any.

That part is easy. What I'm struggling with is figuring out how to handle requests that need authentication. I use Firebase Auth for that and my question is - how/where should I acquire the auth token to pass via headers?

Right now I have this:

```js
class GraphQL {
  
  async executedAthenticatedQuery(query, variables, requestHeaders) {
    const token = getAuthHeaders();
    if (token) {
        const authHeaders = { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
    } else {
        throw new Error("User not logged in");
    }

    return this.executeBaseQuery(query, variables, {...authHeaders, ...requestHeaders});
  }

  async executeQuery(query, variables = {}, requestHeaders = {}) {
    return this.executeBaseQuery(query, variables, requestHeaders);
  }

  async executeBaseQuery(query, variables = {}, requestHeaders = {}) {
    const body = JSON.stringify(query);

    const response = await fetch("https://myapi.com/v1", {
      method: "POST",
      body,
      headers: {
       ...requestHeaders
      }
    });

    return response.json();
}

function getAuthToken() {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      if (Firebase.auth().currentUser !== null) {
        Firebase.auth()
          .currentUser.getIdToken()
          .then(data => res(data));
      } else {
        this.firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
          if (user) {
            user.getIdToken().then(data => res(data));
          } else {
            rej(null);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

I want to be able to call these functions from my Redux actions. Is this the best way to do it?

Comment: auth before each query? redux? apollo maybe?

Comment: How would I execute a query with Apollo via Redux?

Comment: instead ... redux for app state, apollo for data fetching

Comment: Okay, that is an option, yes, but the app already uses Redux. I do not wish to rewrite the whole app.

Comment: you can use both, no need to duplicate apollo cached, normalized data in redux state ... but you can use apollo client from redux reducers/sagas/whatever ... for old app parts (until refactoring, if ever) and use apollo directly for new FCs using useQuery